# Unable to write large String to a file

Tags: java, string, file

I am trying to print a large string(single line) into a file. But the string is getting truncated in between. Any idea on why this is happening?

```
void writeToFile(String schemaString,String message){

    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Servicelog.txt", true);                     
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        fw.write(new Timestamp(date.getTime())+"\n");
        fw.write(message+"\n");         
        fw.write("schemaBegins\n"+schemaString+"\n"+"schemaEnds");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remember to close the file.

```
FileWriter fw = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Servicelog.txt", true);
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    fw.write(new Timestamp(date.getTime()) + "\n");
    fw.write(message + "\n");
    fw.write("schemaBegins\n" + schemaString + "\n" + "schemaEnds");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if ( fw != null ) {
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Java7 and newer encapsulate that mechanism using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Servicelog.txt", true) ) {
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    fw.write(new Timestamp(date.getTime()) + "\n");
    fw.write(message + "\n");
    fw.write("schemaBegins\n" + schemaString + "\n" + "schemaEnds");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Writing to any `Writer` can be buffered, leaving some of the data unwritten if you do not close it.

Comment: Calling `fw.flush()` will also flush the stream, if you don't want to close `FileWriter` right away for some reason.

Comment: I dont know how I missed it out. Thanks a lot for pointing it out to me. I was wasting my time analysing FileWrite, PrintWriter etc...